# What solid, scalable, well known frameworks/cms exist to build a community?

Tags: web-applications, scalability

I'm a mobile developer, I developed an Android app that I need to interface with a community (still to build). A this point, I clearly have in mind how this community should look like, but I'm still thinking/researching how to build it, since I have really little experience in creating web apps. So I need any kind of suggestions, tips, tricks and so on about it.
What should be considered is:

- users should be able to post articles, comments, etc.
- users must me able to create profiles
- the community will communicate with the mobile app, so I need some API to interface with (create web services, etc.).
- the community should be able to scale as much as it needs, easily (in case of the community success). With "easily" I mean I don't
  want to deal with the scaling issue by myself, so I would prefer some solution that scales by itself. I want a "pay as you go" model, where you pay as you need (as app engine, for example)
- I don't want to deal with system management (installing and managing databases, doing backups, etc.)
- all the project will have some business related part (selling stuff, services, etc.), so no restrictions must exist from this point of view.

What I've looked so far:

wordpress: I'm not sure how easily it can scale, and if a "pay as you go" model exists (any hosting service able to do that, professionally?). Should I take care of installing, managing, backing up the database by myself (I think so)?

wordpress.com seems interesting, but the service has a lot of restrictions, unfortunately.

joomla/drupal: more or less the same doubts as for wordpress

app engine: I would like to use it, really! It scales, you pay just what you need, there is a great amount of free resources. Besides, it uses java. The biggest problem here is that I'm not aware of an existing solid framework/cms to start with, and I don't want to build all the community from scratch! Any business-solid framework/cms/anything else exists? any direct experience with it?
I did research this last point (app engine solutions) for some days, but nothing convincing came up (seen google thoughtsite, vosao, among others).

Any help?

Thanks so much!

---

ADDED

---

Before posting this question I've thoroughly read other similar posts. But all replies do not fit my question, at least not entirely. Besides, most posts are dated, considering that even few months in this field are an "eternity".
That said, I'll try to be more specific (and to narrow a bit the question):
I'd like to use app engine for building a community, as described above, using JAVA (important). I'd prefer to use some cms or at least some framework rather than building all from scratch. I'm aware of just two possibilities that seem reasonably known: google thoughtsite, vosao. The first appears to have low activity, the second one seems just a bit better, but I read that only one developer actually is contributing.
So, what I like to hear from you all, is any kind of advises, tips, and, most preferably, direct experience in using one of this tools (do they fit? are reasonably stable/mature?). Or any other direct experience with other possibilities that fit app engine + java.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but these types of questions get asked a lot. It's impossible to answer them objectively, and as such they aren't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointed this out, I better clarified why my request is different from previous ones and also I narrowed my request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Codeigniter+Memcache+Php+phphiphop technologie + MySql + MongoDB+ Jquery+ a bit hands and  time time time